# Uploading xml file and image file together with same submit using one ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, image-uploading

I want to send uploaded image and uploaded XML to PHP file using one ajax. I used two form data, Is this the correct way to do it.

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="fileToUpload" id="uploadFile"/>
<input type="file" name="imageToUpload" id="uploadImg"/>
<input type="submit" id="upload_xml" name="transcriptform" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-info">
```

Ajax call:

```
$('#upload_xml').on('click', function() {
   var file_data = $('#uploadFile').prop('files')[0];   
   var form_data = new FormData();
   form_data.append('file', file_data);

   var img_data = $('#uploadImg').prop(files('files')[0];
   var img_form = new FormData();
   img_form.append('img', img_data);

         $.ajax({
             url: "get_old_contents.php",
           //dataType: 'script',
           //cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             data: form_data,img_form;      //is this correct                  
             type: 'post',
             complete: function(response){
             $('#res').html('Your files are uploaded successfully!');                
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. You need to send a single `FormData` object in the `data` property of the `$.ajax` call. To do that you can use `append()` to add both files together, like this:

```
$('#yourForm').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var form_data = new FormData();
   var file_data = $('#uploadFile').prop('files')[0];   
   var img_data = $('#uploadImg').prop('files')[0];

   form_data.append('file', file_data);
   form_data.append('img', img_data);

   $.ajax({
     // ...
     data: form_data,
  });
});
```

You can also simplify this if you can change the `name` attribute of the file inputs, by providing a reference to the `<form>` element to the constructor of the `FormData` object:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file" id="uploadFile"/>
<input type="file" name="img" id="uploadImg"/>
```

```js
$('#yourForm').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var form_data = new FormData(this);    
   $.ajax({
     // ...
     data: form_data,
  });
});
```

Note that in both cases you should be hooking to the `submit` event of the `form` element, not click of the button, and using `preventDefault()` on the event argument of the handler to stop the standard form submission.

Comment: I am trying this.

Comment: Note that I just expanded the answer a little to show you a slightly better way of handling form submissions

Comment: I tried this, form will refresh the page, I dont want that to happen because I am right away reading the contents and displaying on page

Comment: If the page is refreshing then you have an error somewhere, as `e.preventDefault()` stops the form submission.

Comment: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $img_path);   and I should be able to upload both to server like this right? In a similar way that uploaded only xml before